# Unable to get a widget name by Gtk.Buildable.get_name(obj)

Tags: widget, gtk, pygtk

I'd like to show and hide some windows and logging their names.

But i'm unable to do it, so i printed some interesting facts:

```
print Gtk.Buildable.get_name(menuitem)
print menuitem.get_toplevel()
print Gtk.Buildable.get_name(menuitem.get_toplevel())

--- OUTPUT -----------------------------------------------

Configurazione2_Menuitem
<Window object at 0x7f81880e7280 (GtkWindow at 0x15b9a40)>
None
```

So i'm unable to hide the current window. Because this one can't work:

```
menuitem.get_toplevel().hide() #hide_currentwindow
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to hide from the menu item? Is it the window the contains the menu item in question or a different floating window? A small run-able example showing what doesn't work would help.

Comment: i simply want to hide the window where the menuitem is included

Answer (score -1):

name, hide and show properties are linked to the gtk.widget

```
>>> import gtk
>>> w = gtk.Window()
>>> w.get_name()
'GtkWindow'
>>> w.set_name("test")
>>> w.get_name()
'test'
>>> 
>>> w.show()
>>> w.hide()
>>>
```

Comment: i don't know if you have read my question, i'm gonna hide the current window by the menuitem inside it. I can get the menuitem name, but i can't get the window name.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me.

The code below opens a window with a MenuItem and Button, pressing the button hides the window by getting a reference to it by calling `MenuItem.get_toplevel().hide()`

Now, this answers the question *as stated in your post*, but not the question in the title. You don't say why you want to get the widget's name, only that you want to hide a window when you have a ref to a child MenuItem.

```
import gtk
import time

class MyWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        win = gtk.Window()
        win.connect('destroy',gtk.main_quit)

        self.menu = gtk.MenuItem('MenuItem')
        hbox = gtk.HBox()
        hbox.pack_start(self.menu)

        btn = gtk.Button('HideMe')
        btn.connect('pressed',self.hide_me)
        hbox.pack_start(btn)

        win.add(hbox)
        win.show_all()

    def hide_me(self, widget):
        self.menu.get_toplevel().hide()
        print 'Hiding'
        time.sleep(2)
        print 'Showing'
        self.menu.get_toplevel().show()

MyWindow()
gtk.main()
```

Edit:
A simpler version:

```
import gtk
import time

class MyWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        win = gtk.Window()
        win.connect('destroy',gtk.main_quit)
        win.set_size_request(50,50)
        menuitem = gtk.MenuItem()
        menuitem.set_label("I'm a Menuitem")
        win.add(menuitem)
        win.show_all()
        print 'Hiding window now...'
        menuitem.get_toplevel().hide()
        print 'Showing window now...'
        time.sleep(2)
        menuitem.get_toplevel().show()
MyWindow()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: I'm using a Gtk.Menuitem, not a Gtk.Button: please try to do the same i've done. You have to use ***menuitem.get_toplevel().hide()*** to hide the window of the menuitem

Comment: I used a gtk.Button because I can't see that a gtkMenuItem has a signal that I could use to trigger the callback. I've edited the code to clarify it a bit: in the callback, you can see that I'm explicitly referencing the menuitem in the line `self.menu.get_toplevel().hide()`

Comment: for the menuitem you have to use the "activate" signal; anyway any widget has the "get_top_level" callback, because it is inherited from the Gtk.Widget class

Comment: Agreed. The way I see it, you have posted two separate questions: *1) Unable to get a widget name by Gtk.Buildable.get_name(obj)* and *2) Unable to hide widget by using menuitem.get_toplevel().hide()*. I've shown that 2) does work for me, and asked that you show us your code. 1) is a different issue. Are you using Glade, by chance?

Comment: yes i've been using Glade, but the problem is that i can retrieve the window object, but not the window name; it's the 1 time that "Gtk.Buildable.get_name()" doesn't work for me.
The 2) problem you've said doesn't exist at this moment, since i get
"None" from "Gtk.Buildable.get_name(menuitem.get_toplevel)"

Comment: The thing is, I don't understand *why* you need to get the name. If you are simply trying to hide the window, then you can do that with the window object that you got with this: `print menuitem.get_toplevel()`. At least you can with hand-crafted gtk.

Comment: **menuitem.get_toplevel()** doesn't work, that is the reason why i'm using the other way. You have to run your example by a menuitem object

Comment: "menuitem.get_toplevel() doesn't work" **Yes. It. Does.** In the second line of your original post: `print menuitem.get_toplevel()`, the response is `<Window object at 0x7f81880e7280 (GtkWindow at 0x15b9a40)>`. "You have to run your example by a menuitem object" **I am** `self.menu` is a menuitem object. `self.menu.get_toplevel().hide()` hides it. You still haven't shown us your code.

Comment: The code is the simplest you can imagine: a really basic window, with a menubar (4 menuitems, children of a top menuitem called "Menu"). The UI is provided by Glade, the files and code are too long, you have just to know that everything works, but i can't hide the window.
**menuitem.get_toplevel()** doesn't work. Please try by yourself instead of telling me that it works; i know that the *print* output is correct, i'm able to read, that's because is a strange fact.

Comment: I have tried myself, as you could see if you actually looked at / tried the code above. Do me a favour: try the second bit of code I've just posted above. Line 14 is the interesting one.